# How to write a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler with Cron?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to write my first taskExecutor, and I have some doubts.

I need to execute 3 tasks at the same time.

Is my configuration correct?

Should the configuration be with the tasks in the same bean? (Best Practice)

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskExecutor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TaskExecutor.class);

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 55 23 28-31 * ?")
    public void firstTask() throws ParseException {

        }               
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 55 23 28-31 * ?")
    public void secondTask() {

        }       
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 55 23 28-31 * ?")
    public void thirdTask() {

        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        LOGGER.info("Setting up thread pool task scheduler with 3 threads.");
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(3);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("task-");
        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        scheduler.setErrorHandler(t -> LOGGER.error(
                "Unknown error occurred while executing task.", t
        ));
        scheduler.setRejectedExecutionHandler(
                (r, e) -> LOGGER.error(
                        "Execution of task {} was rejected for unknown reasons.", r
                )
        );
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do as below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    logger.info("Cron Task :: Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
}
```

or, you can 
use **`CronTrigger`**  to schedule a task based on a cron expression as below:

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger   = new CronTrigger("10 * * * * ?");
```

The provided trigger can be used to run a task according to a certain specified cadence or schedule:

```
taskScheduler.schedule(new RunnableTask("Cron Trigger"), cronTrigger);
```

In this case, the RunnableTask will be executed at the 10th second of every minute.

Comment: I am not understanding what is different about the first proposed point